# Adding debug output scrabbles result from function

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, bash-functions

I have a function that returns a value.
But I would like to add some `echo`s for easier debugging. But this scrabbles the result.
Example:

```
function foo {
   echo "In foo"
   VAR="1234"
   echo "Calculated item"
   echo "$VAR"
}

RESULT=$(foo)
echo "RESULT=$RESULT"
```

I was expecting to get `1234`.
Instead the output is:

```
RESULT=In foo  
Calculated item  
1234
```

What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: 1) there's no return statement 2) in bash, you can't return a string, it's the output STDOUT that is returned, so this behavior is just normal 3) in 2018, to declare function, just use : `f() { }`

Comment: @GillesQuenot:Is that definition ok for all platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect the debugging output to standard error:

```
foo () {
   echo 'In foo' >&2
   VAR="1234"
   echo 'Calculated item' >&2
   echo "$VAR"
}

RESULT=$(foo)
printf 'RESULT="%s"\n' "$RESULT"
```

You could even create a dedicated "debug" function:

```
debug () {
    printf 'DEBUG: %s\n' "$@" >&2
}

foo () {
   debug 'In foo'
   VAR="1234"
   debug 'Calculated item'
   echo "$VAR"
}

RESULT=$(foo)
printf 'RESULT="%s"\n' "$RESULT"
```

Output:

```
$ sh script.sh
DEBUG: In foo
DEBUG: Calculated item
RESULT="1234"
```